# How do I speed up and stabilize Word and Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, crash, microsoft-office-2013

We recently changed servers and moved to Office 2013.

Now we have the problem that some files open extremely slow and cause the application (Word or Excel) to crash.

For Word we've added the registry key: UseTimeoutForAttachedTemplateLoad

The registry key seems to work, but only if Word is already running. If it's not, and we open a file from Windows Explorer which has a link to a template on the old server, the registry key is ignored. Is there a way to force this registry key to not be ignored, even when opening a Word document from Explorer?

In addition, some files have links to other files, not templates, and if these are on the old server this also causes extreme slowness and crashes. Is there a way to work around this?

Even though roaming profiles and folder redirection are properly pointing to the new server and function correctly, Word itself is also slow to open (from start menu), unless the old server is turned on and connected to the network. Any ideas how this fix this?

In addition, Excel seems to just randomly crash, even when opening a newly created file into which was pasted (values only) data from another file on which it crashed.

We have installed all the updates for Office 2013. We have also created new profiles for part of the users (after changing the server), and see no difference between users with old profiles and those with new profiles. We have also verified that the users do indeed get the UseTimeoutForAttachedTemplateLoad registry key in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue too, but could enahance it by allowing trusted network location and add the shared folder location as trusted location, try it it might help you also.
Option -> Trust Center-> Trust Center Settings... -> Trusted Document

and on same box, add your network folder to Trusted Locations